# How can I make git stop printing to the screen?

Tags: git, shell, cron

I have cron job that uses git pull to synch a particular repository to it's origin. The command looks like this:

```
@daily echo $(cd /path/to/dir && git pull origin master) > /dev/null
```

but I still get

```
From https://github.com/groupname/reponame
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But cron still sends me mail with output whenever the directory is updated. **How can I stop git from producing any output?**

Comment: you're only redirecting stdout. try redirecting stderr as well. e.g. `2>&1 > /dev/null`

Comment: @MarcB this way you duplicate `stdout` as `stderr` then redirect only `stdout` to `/dev/null`. The order is important; `2>&1` must stay after `>/dev/null`.

Comment: I would write the two commands (`cd` and `git`) into a script file. This way you have better control of the output (can redirect the output and the errors of `git` to `/dev/null` or to different files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe option `--quiet` will be enough?

Documentation:

> -q, --quiet
>
> This is passed to both underlying git-fetch to squelch reporting of during transfer, and underlying git-merge to squelch 
>   output during merging.

Answer (score -1):

Add this to your command:

```
> /dev/null 2>&1 

@daily echo $(cd /path/to/dir && git pull origin master) 2>&1 > /dev/null 2&1
```

#### Whats does it means?

```
File descriptor 1 is the standard output (stdout).
File descriptor 2 is the standard error (stderr).
```

Looks like the `2>1` will redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, but the twist here that it will actually redirect `stderr` to a file named `1`.

This will do the trick :-)

Comment: `2>&1` doesn't redirect anything. It **duplicates** the `stdout` (file descriptor 1) as `stderr` (file descriptor 2). `stdout` being already redirected to `/dev/null`, it means `stderr` will also be redirected to `/dev/null`. The order is important: the redirection must occur **before** the duplication; otherwise only `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null` and `stderr` goes where `stdout` was before (i.e. on screen).

Comment: Feel free to update the answer with any new information you have so other can benefit from it.